# c# check domain is live

Tags: c#, networking, hostname

I want to know how I can check if the domain is a live in c#?

I made this

```
IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses("domain");
```

it returns the IP(s), which is good, but I want to check if it is live (like ping)?

I just need to know if the PC is in the same network as the server, so I have a function to check but the functions based on the code above, and it return IPs but I noticed it is based on the cached DNS!

I want to add another check function to see if the server is online!

cheers

Comment: What is "live" to you? That you can ping it? That is has a webserver that is running?

Comment: that the server is up and running, simply the program will check the domain and see if it is up, then (I have this done) it will check the IP address matches with the original, simply it is a checking mechanism for an internal app that it will preform some task only if the machine is connected to our network at work

Comment: @Data-Base - would it be bad if it worked when not connected to your network? Because hosts and IP addresses are easily cloned/spoofed.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, no it is not bad, it is just a simple app that we build to do some task, not a critical!

Comment: @Data-Base, you have added a bounty, is there anything you miss in the answers below?

Comment: Try running an LDAP query on the domain controller - if you get an exception, then the domain controller is hosed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [System.Net.NetworkInformation.OperationalStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.operationalstatus?view=netframework-2.0) Property allow you to detect if your network interface is connected (up).

The [NetworkInterface.GetIPProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getipproperties?view=netframework-2.0) Method will give you the IP informations.

You can use this to check if the computer is on lan, then do what you need -like a ping- if connected.

Comment: Thanks That sounds very good way to start, I will test it on Thursday, when I will be at work :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`Ping.Send(IPAddress)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb7xxkfx.aspx) method.

Edit: Or one of the overloads that takes the hostname directly.
[`Ping.Send(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hzczzed.aspx)

Example from MSDN:

```
Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
PingReply reply = pingSender.Send ("www.contoso.com");
if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Address: {0}", reply.Address.ToString ());
    Console.WriteLine ("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
    Console.WriteLine ("Time to live: {0}", reply.Options.Ttl);
    Console.WriteLine ("Don't fragment: {0}", reply.Options.DontFragment);
    Console.WriteLine ("Buffer size: {0}", reply.Buffer.Length);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine (reply.Status);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but the else does not work for me! it just show nothing

Comment: @Data-Base, with the exact example and the hostname above I get `TimedOut` on my console. What happens if you put a breakpoint in the else-part?

Comment: funny, now it worked with the example above ("www.contoso.com") but when I use our domain it does work only when my PC is connected to the network, when I disconnect the cable then it does not sjow the timeout thing! !!!

Comment: Don't forget the firewall on the target may be blocking ping requests.

Comment: still, it is good, that gives the app a message not to run some functions, which is good

Comment: the idea is to check if the PC is on the same line where there is a server with an IP(s) and a domain name (hostname) if the app can not reach the server (for what ever reason) and the domian does not match the IP then it will run some functions, nothing fancy

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform any kind of task with a remote system, then no amount of pre-checking will ensure that you're able to carry out the task - networks and hosts are not 100% reliable, and what *was* true during your checking operations may no longer be true when attempting the actual task, or throughout the duration of performing the task.

The only sane thing to do is to attempt the task you need to perform, and deal with errors, timeouts, etc, in a safe manner. This may be letting the user know of the failure, or retrying it (possibly with increasing delays between each attempt), or just logging the error somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I just need to know if some host is live! and if it is then the program will work (it is an app for our internal use at work), cheers